# Android - Equivalent to .NET web.config transformations

Tags: android, .net

I'm new to Android programming and was wondering if there is an equivalent to .NET's web.config transformations.

An example of what I'd like to do is store my web service urls in a config file and switch these out to hit different servers depending on whether I am in dev/test/release mode.

What is the best mechanism to use to store such settings and is there a method to change these based on the run configuration I use?
Thank you
JP

Answer (score 0):

Web.config transforms have nothing to do with .NET.  They are an implementation detail of the publishing system in Visual Studio.  As such, they are a visual studio feature, not a .net feature.

Consequently, since web.config transforms are not a part of .net, they also would not be a part of android.  They could be a part of Eclipse, or Titanium Studio or whatever IDE you're using, but I don't know of any such feature in them.